# Unable to download .apk in android 5.0 from website

Tags: android, download, server

Need help.

We have two servers that deploy the website. The website has a link that can download an .apk file to a mobile.

The problem is, when site is access in mobile using android 4.x, it downloads successfully on both server. However, when using android 5 (lollipop), it download successfully in one server but unsuccessful in another.

the mime type for both server is the same (application/vnd.android.packa..). Certificate for both server is ok also (although they have different issuer, which I don't think is an issue)

I also check the properties of the website, and its the same.

Is there are any setting in web server that I need to check or any security setting that makes one server download successfully the apk file while the other does not?

Appreciate any thought on this.

Comment: `The website has a link that can download an .apk file `. Please show how that <a> tag looks like. `access in mobile using android 4.x`. It is unclear how you access the site. In a browser? Which one? In your app?

Comment: the link is just a basic  <a href="<server>/filename.apk" target=_blank>Android</a>

Comment: And you deliberately do not answer my other questions?